# MS Access: Get Record from Listbox without DLookup

Tags: ms-access, listbox

I have three tables: Article, Order, OrderDetail.

In the Orderdetail Subform of the Order Form I have a Listbox named 'ChoseArticle' that is linked to the table 'Article' (not to a Query).

Now if the user choses one of the articles in the Listbox, it can undoubtedly be stated that the article record just chosen is well defined. How do I access the fields of the chosen article record WITHOUT using DLookup?

`Article![Art-No]` gives a type mismatch error.

`ChoseArticle.[Art-No]` gives an error Method or Object not found

`Me.ChoseArticle` gives me the first Listbox column of the chosen article.

But how to access the other fields of the chosen article?

Note that my Article table intentionally has no primary key.

Comment: Let me put it in an even simpler form : I have a Listbox where one record from a table can be chosen by simply clicking on one of the entries. Do I have access now to all fields of that record WITHOUT accessing the database a second time with DLookup? If yes please tell me how. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the solution myself:

First of all, in the subform's Listbox, set the number of columns of the list fields equal to the number of fields (n) in the 'Article' table.

Second, choose the column widths, e.g. `2cm;2cm;2cm;0cm;0cm;0cm ...`, again for as many fields as there are in the table (n).

Third, access the fields of the chosen record with `Me.ChoseArticle.Column(x)`, where x is between 0 and n-1, and `ChoseArticle` is the name of the Listbox.

`Dlookup()` is therefore not necessary, which comes in handy when accessing records of tables with no primary key.